# Enforcing Type of Attribute of Argument of Custom Type

Tags: python, type-hinting

Working with Python's `typing` module, I would like to create a custom Type that checks for the type of an attribute of an argument. To be more precise, in my case the argument's type is supposed to be an instance of a certain class, and the attribute is supposed to be of a certain Type.

What I want to achieve might be clearer with a minimal example:

```
class Wrapper:
    value: typing.Any


def f(obj: WrapperType[int]) -> None:
    assert isinstance(obj, Wrapper) and type(obj.value) is int
```

How can I create a `WrapperType` that reflects the behaviour of this `assert` (in terms of typing)? I was unable to find hints for this in the documentation of the `typing` module. But I am not sure whether I misunderstood something in there, or whether what I want is just not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Wrapper` should inherit from `Typing.Generic`.

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

class Wrapper(Generic[T]):
    value: T


def f(obj: Wrapper[int]) -> None:
    ...
```